# Granting Delete Permission for Content Type in Plone4

Tags: plone

I'm trying to come up with the 'right' way to grant certain roles in a Plone4 installation the right to delete certain content types. So far, I've managed to restrict the visibility of the Delete Action via an expression and a new Permission ("Delete Articles") - if the object in question is an Article and the user has the right to delete articles, the button is shown.

The problem is that the user still needs the "Delete Objects" permission to actually delete the article, but granting a role that user has that permissions allows him to delete anything, not just the content types I want. Is there any way I can grant the permission to delete a specific content type to a role, something along the lines of an 'ArticleDeleter' role for instance?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Check https://github.com/4teamwork/collective.deletepermission

Quote out of the Readme:

> The collective.deletepermission package introduces an additional
>   permission Delete portal content. By seperating the permission Delete
>   portal content (I can delete this content object) from the permission
>   Delete objects (I can delete something IN this folder), we now can
>   allow a Contributor to delete content he created (Owner role) without
>   letting him delete folders and objects belonging to other users - even
>   in a nested environment.